# Alignment, raster time-series, R

Tags: raster, r, landsat, clip, time-series

I have a Landsat raster time-series (2000-2016) of 102 rasters for the same location. Since the original Landsat scenes don't overlap exactly, I defined a polygon to use for cropping all the rasters to the same extent, since I need to stack them.

I work in R and used this function to batch process my time-series:

```
processLandsatBatch(x=listzip, pattern=glob2rx('*.zip'), outdir=output_gz, srdir=srdir, delete=TRUE, vi='ndmi', mask='fmask', keep=0, e= Riau_sp, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Riau_sp is my extent polygon.

However in the output I see that the rasters still don't have exactly the same extent, and I get ERROR when I try to stack them. Here is an example of two of my rasters extent after processing:

`extent: 101.6222, 102.8827, -0.6339126, 0.6637299  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`

`extent: 101.6222, 102.8827, -0.6339154, 0.6637271  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`

The y-values are just a bit off, even though both were cropped with the same extent-polygon.

Any idea what has happened, and how I may fix it?